# how works commit timestamp internally

Tags: postgresql

those files are present in folder /pg_commit_ts

```
-rw-------.  1 postgres postgres 262144 Jun 17 12:56 0000
-rw-------.  1 postgres postgres 262144 Jun 17 12:56 0001
-rw-------.  1 postgres postgres 262144 Jun 17 12:57 0002
...
```

Are thoses files created only if track_commit_timestamp is on?

Comment: Test it. Set track_commit_timestamp off and run a set of transactions and see what happens.

Comment: Tks for your suggestion. Do you know if it is possible to get the last statement that was commited?

Comment: Perhaps depending on you exact need. See documentation [System Information Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these files are only created if `track_commit_timestamp = on`. You cannot get the last committed statement, but you can use `pg_last_committed_xact()` to get the timestamp and transaction ID of the last committed transaction (see [the documentation](https://%20pg_last_committed_xact)).